# How to pass the name of the button on Onclick in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

**View Code:**

```
<input type="button" value="Haghway Lite"  onclick="window.location='panelview/'+objButton.value;" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;width:100%;height:100%;" >
```

This is the code I have tried.But it doesn't works.

Comment: And where is the code?

Comment: And `objButton` is what?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function one function for navigate and pass a value.does this help.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" value="Haghway Lite"  onclick="move(this)" style="background-color:transparent;border:none;width:100%;height:100%;" >
```

**Javascript**

```
 function move(component)
    {
        window.location="panelview/"+component.value
    }
```

Comment: How to use the same in ROUTE and CONTROLLER